# PendingIntent resume activity

Tags: android

I have an Android activity that places a Notification in the status bar.  Selecting the notification will launch my main activity.  The problem is that this `PendingIntent` always starts a new instance of my activity "MyappMain".  So when i start my app by clicking on the notification, i get an new instance of the MyappMain and then i must quit/finish them all one by one (if I clicked multiple times on the notification).

```
     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyappMain.class);
     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

     notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
     mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add `finish();` before you start a new Intent, this way your current activity will be finished and new one will be started.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the "FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT" flag.

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```